# Freshely Installed Nginx Reverse proxy with certbot showing 404 error page

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, certbot

I have installed NGINX reverse proxy with certbot through Docker but i t is not showing the welcome page for Nginx rather it is taking me to a 404 error. when i did the  below command `nginx -t`
it gave me the following result

```
> nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

this is what is in my domain config file

```
    server{                                                                                             
                server_name domainname.com www.domainname.com;                                            
        location / {                                                                                
                proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:80;                                                    
              }                                                                                     
                                                                                                    
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot                                                            
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot           
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot         
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot                           
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot                             
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                   
server{                                                                                             
    if ($host = www.domainname.com) {                                                                  
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;                                                       
    } # managed by Certbot                                                                          
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
    if ($host = domainname.com) {                                                                      
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;                                                       
    } # managed by Certbot                                                                          
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                listen 80;                                                                          
                server_name domainname.com www.domainname.com;                                            
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

Please any advice in resolving this issue will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Which URL is resulting in the 404? What is running at 172.17.0.2:80?

Comment: the `dominame.com` is resulting to 404 . I am running `another application` at 172.17.0.2 that i do not want to run publicly but will run through the `domainname.com/anythinghere` whereby `anythinghere` is being generated by the `another application`

Comment: Is the 404 coming from `another application` maybe? A full `curl` request/response would help much. DNS records set up properly? From the information you provided it's impossible to tell unfortunately.